# What are the commands to check database security in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, security

I am looking for PostgreSQL commands that would help me understand what are the current database security measures implemented in my database?

e.g. I have found this one `select * from pg_catalog.pg_roles;` When used in DBeaver, the command basically shows all the roles that currently exist in my database and shows them in the table, the screenshot below. However, I am not sure what [v], [], or [NULL] values mean in this context. Your advice is appreciated on this matter as well.
[image]

Comment: Looks like [v] means "true" [] means "false" [NULL] means not specified.

Comment: Your question really seems to be about how some unspecified tool chooses to display values on the screen.  At least identify what that tool is.